# JAX-RS 2.0 Validation

Tags: java, jax-rs

I am reading that the following validation should work with JAX-RS 2.0.

```
    public Response getEvent(@PathParam("lagdays")
                               @Pattern(regexp = "[0-7]", message = "Lag Days must be between 0 and 7")
                               Integer lagDays,
                               @Context HttpServletResponse res) {
```

However, I get the message shown below when I run it

```
HV000030: No validator could be found for type: java.lang.Integer.
```

How can I determine what version of JAX-RS that I am on?  I looked in my pom file and I do not see anything for JAX-RS.  I am using Java 7.

I am thinking that I am not using JAX-RS 2.0, or that I have a syntax error somewhere.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware, `@Pattern` is only valid on `CharSequence`s ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html)).  If you want your numbers to be in an range, use `@Min` and `@Max`